# Update number of views of a question with AJAX

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, views

Currently some things on a question page update "dynamically" (with AJAX without page reload). That includes the number of votes for a question and some other things.

I propose to update dynamically also the number of views of the question. Personally I often click Reload in the browser to see if the number of views has changed. I think this should be automated and without full page reload.

Comment: What real use does this have, other than making watching a post more like a movie? If you keep reloading just to watch the view counter go up, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one of the least interesting metrics about a question. And it certainly does not need to be updated in real-time.

Comment: I recall from comments or a discussion in chat that viewcount is also not *live* as votes are. Viewcount is updated by  a batch that runs?

Comment: I don't recall for sure, but wouldn't surprise me.