# What stats are refreshed automatically, other than post score?

Tags: support, live-refresh

I sometimes see some information, like post score, being updated by itself, without having to reload the page. Other things, like edits, require reloading to see.

What things are updating automatically inside posts via this live refresh?

Comment: I have clarified the question, now it should be clear enough to be reopened.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is a complete rewrite. Good effort!

Comment: @Patrick thanks, luckily it was clear to me what OP here actually wanted, since I wondered about it myself sometimes. :)

Comment: Party answered in the [websockets answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/158100)

Answer (score 3):

From personal observations, this is the list of "live" information in posts:

- Score (posts only, not comments, instant)
- Time stamps: (rate of refresh: one minute)

  - asked/answered
  - edited
  - comments
- Banners (requires clicking to load)

  - closure of question (also cause the answer submit button to become disabled)
  - addition of new posts
  - edits of existing posts
  - deletion of already loaded posts
  - new comments added

Related feature requests:

- [Update number of views of a question with AJAX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283632/update-number-of-views-of-a-question-with-ajax) (declined)

If anyone observes anything else, feel free to add it here as well.

Comment: Timestamps is just a clent-side *trick*. That is not really *refreshed*

Comment: @rene not relevant for the end user. What matters is the final result: the time is "live".